# C# Increasing Console Log Size

Tags: c#

i have a basic C# Console application, it retrives logs from a website, but after like 100 lines, the old logs are deleted and the user cant scroll up and see them anymore, is there any way to increase the size it will save?

Comment: does you application needs to show logs on screen ? how about writing to a log file instead.

Comment: Hi, i was trying to generate a log file.txt but its seems too difficult to me, since im a newbie.. if you got a good tut to show me how to do it, it will be nice :P

Comment: It's likely more advanced than you need, but log4net seems to be a good logger: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Answer (score 11):

Console.SetBufferSize() buys you a bigger buffer.  There are a few complications however.  There's an upper limit on the maximum size and there's a bug in the argument validation code in the SetBufferSize() method.  It reports that Int16.MaxValue is the largest number of lines you can ask for.  That's an off-by-one bug.  On Windows 7 you can use:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.SetBufferSize(Console.BufferWidth, 32766);
    // etc..
}
```

On older operating systems (like XP) there a much tighter limit, the buffer size used to be restricted to 65536 bytes.  I don't have them around anymore to check.  The *possibly* valid code on those is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var lines = 65536 / 2 / Console.BufferWidth;
        Console.SetBufferSize(Console.BufferWidth, lines);
        // etc..
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Console.SetBufferSize()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setbuffersize.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Console.SetOut might also help you in redirecting console output to a file. Follow the link for an example.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/DemonstratesredirectingtheConsoleoutputtoafile.htm